# can't use dynamic assigned data attribute in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element with class ROW. I do a $.each($(".row) and assign a data-id attribute containing an unique id.
But when I try to select the element it can't find id.

I can run $(".row").data("id") in debugger in Firefox and I get the correct value, but when I try to select $(".row[data-id='1']") it doesnt find any element and doesn't show any data attribute in Inspector in Firefox.

If I define data-id in the html it works as expected, but I need to assign the value dynamically.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
...
</div>

$.each($(".row"), function (i) {
    var $row = $(this);

    $row.data("id", i);
});
```

Select:

```
$(".row[data-id='1']"); //returns nothing

$(".row").data("id"); //returns 0 (expected)
```

Comment: Try `$row.attr("data-id", i)`

Comment: there aren't any `.row`s with a `data-id` attribute in your markup

Comment: Lucia Kiebel: no because it is set dynamically in $.each loop

Comment: @MartinAdámek that returned undefined. $row.data("id") works, but not when trying to select it using $(".row[data-id='1']")

Comment: Well if you have just one `.row`, then there is no `data-id=1`, as it starts from zero and the first one is `data-id=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.attr('data-id', ...)` instead of `$.data('id', ...)`.

Also note that you are trying to access element `data-id=1`, that does not exist if you have just one `.row` element.

```js
$.each($(".row"), function (i) {
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.attr("data-id", i);
});

console.log($('.row[data-id=1]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
1...
</div>

<div class="row">
2...
</div>
```

`$.data` will set internal data attribute value, while `$.attr` will add the attribute to DOM.